Broken Jupyter notebook menus on Chrome
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and use Chrome as my default browser. Recently I have noticed issues with the Jupyter interface when I run it on Chrome. Specifically:

In the Jupyter notebook dashboard the context buttons (open/rename/...) are arranged vertically rather than horizontally, and appear with a text label rather than an icon (screenshot);
In an open notebook most of action buttons (cut/paste/...) do not appear at all (screenshot);
In Jupyter lab the File Browser action buttons (new/upload/refresh/...) are also arranged vertically (screenshot).

This seems to be related to a recent update of Chrome, as I did not encounter this problem before April (2024). On Firefox 124.0.2 both Jupyter notebook and lab work just fine.
What I have tried so far (with Chrome), without success:

Accessing Jupyter via 127.0.0.1;
Disabling Chrome extensions;
Clearing Chrome's cache;
Running Jupyter without user settings ($ jupyter lab --LabConfig.user_settings_dir=./empty-jupyter-config)
Erasing my Jupyter user settings (at ~/<user>/.jupyter/lab/user-settings);
Checking Chrome's JavaScript console for errors.

I did not get this issue before updating jupyter on my default python installation. I have no Jupyter extensions installed.
Has anyone encountered the same issue? Any idea of how to fix this?
Version details:

Ubuntu: 22.04.4 LTS
Chrome: 123.0.6312.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Python: 3.10.12 (default python3)
Jupyter/Notebook: See below

$ python3 -m pip freeze | grep jupyter
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.10.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.4
jupyter_client==8.6.1
jupyter_core==5.7.2
jupyter_server==2.13.0
jupyter_server_terminals==0.5.3
jupyterlab==4.1.5
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab_server==2.25.4

$ python3 -m pip freeze | grep notebook
notebook==7.1.2
notebook_shim==0.2.4


 where it emphasizes in bold not to post images. As for your issue, did you recently update any of Jupyter, too? Or are you sure the change in the browser was the only thing? As for help, this seemed similar? And as with here, it don't think it is quite the same issue; however, in the GitHub issue post that I link to from there, there may be some help you could use to troubleshoot ...

 or get to the bottom of the issue. I will say, a lot of time old files that got left around in an upgrade can interfere. That isn't the case if only the browser changed; however, while emphasizing that is what you thought was the case, you haven't ruled out updates to other packages contributing.

Thanks @Wayne for the comments! I've edited my question to make the issue clearer. I've looked at the links you provided and tried the fixes suggested there, without success unfortunately. I'm going to try to pin down an earlier version of jupyter with which I don't get this issue.

NbClassic might also be something to try?

@Wayne So interestingly, nblcassic works just fine. Maybe the issue lies with notebook 7+ then? I am not sure how to try out earlier versions of Jupyter as there are many dependencies.

NbClassic is essentially the next version of Jupyter Notebook after v6.4, yet works with the server that runs Jupyter Notebook 7+ and JupyterLab. (The resources in the second half of my answer here expand on that.) If NbClassic works, I don't see reasons to try the other, older versions of Jupyter Notebook. However, you may later have issues when you want to use a feature of the newer JN7+ and/or JupyyerLab. However, may by then you'll have a new system or decide you'd like the Anaconda Distribution, which does better at isolating things.
